# Changing user's password from console application

Tags: c#, .net, uac

I'm writing a small C# (.NET 4) application that will run as a replacement for the user's "Shell" when logging in to Windows Server 2012. Amongst other things, I'd like to offer the user the chance to change the password of their own **local** account.

Using the following code ..

```
 DirectoryEntry directory = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
 DirectoryEntry userEntry = directory.Children.Find(username);
 userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });

 userEntry.CommitChanges();
```

... works fine if the code is launched from an elevated command prompt. However, as the Shell replacement runs as a "normal" application, I get an

> Access is denied

exception when the code runs, even if the user is set as a local administrator.

Is there any code or mechanisms I can use to programatically set the users own local account passwords without having to elevate? Or (and I'm aware this is maybe more a ServerFault question:) any way to run the "replacement shell" as an elevated process without having to disable UAC?

Comment: Do you have a manifest in your assembly that requests Admin rights? to get past UAC?

Comment: Bingo - I think that`s what I`m missing. I`m now at least prompted for UAC, which I can "manage" with a bit of user training :) Thanks, please feel free to repeat your answer below for some extra points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Manifest to your Assembly to get past the UAC (User Account Control)

In `VS2010` you can add the manifest file to your project. `Right click your project` file on the Solution Explorer, select `Add`, then `New item`. There you can find `Application Manifest File`.

Modify it so that you get one of the following:

1. Normal
2. Highest Available (Depanding on the user permissions)
3. Admin Rights

There are also 2 tools that came with VS2010 that you can use for that:

1. MageUI.exe (Manifest Generation and Editing Tool, Graphical Client)
2. Mage.exe (Manifest Generation and Editing Tool, Command Line)

Answer (score 2):

Change of user's password is a high-privilege operation as you would not want any malicious code from wiping out your existing credentials without your knowledge. You can execute your program from command prompt by using 
`runas /user:<a-priviliged-user> <your-program>.exe`. It will ofcourse prompt you to enter the priviliged-user's password.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a bodge, but have a look at [this page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/616) (although it's from the Vista era it's still relevant).

The idea is you create a scheduled task with embedded credentials to run the application with sufficient credentials but don't actually schedule the task to run. You can then run it on-demand (e.g. during login) with:

```
\windows\system32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "task name"
```

As I say: a bodge, but it might be sufficient for your requirements - the program will run with administrator permissions without prompting for UAC.

EDIT: I've just tried this on Server 2012, and for some reason I can't get a test console app running interactively (i.e. so the user can see the program running). I might just be me, but it could be that behaviour has changed in Server 2012 and this trick might not be suitable for your needs if you need to interact with the user.